# What declaration is this in CSS: font: 0px/0px a;

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

I've been coding for a few years but I have never seen this property:

```
font: 0px/0px a;
```

It caused the text to disappear. What does the **`a`** in `font:` really do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) `font : 0px/0px a;` means a font size of 0px and a line height of 0px. The `a` is an invalid font family name. You can change it with `sdkbgk` you would have the same effect. The font disappear because the font size is 0px. You can make experiments with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSe5K/).